# Mongoose Document.set not saving to actual DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a manual upsert on a `Collection` with a JSON Array.

I loop through the array and first find a match. If a match exists, I call `set` on it - otherwise, I `insert` it into the `collection`.

```
for (let obj of objs) {
    //check for match where 'foo' and 'bar' Objects match
    const match = await Model.findOne({foo:obj.foo, bar:obj.bar});

    if (match) {
        //show value b4 update
        console.log('b4 ', match.fizz);

        //If match, then update the 'fizz' field 
        match.set({fizz:obj.fizz});

        //This actually shows that the update happened
        console.log('after ', match.fizz);
    } else {
      //Otherwise, insert this new Object into the Collection
      await Model.insert(obj)
    }
 }
```

Issue is that the record doesn't get updated in the actual DB when I go into Mongo. Yet, my debugging shows that it has been updated, leading me to believe that the `set` command "worked". Strange thing is that the `insert` seems to work and that I see the new Document in the DB, just not the updated one. Any ideas as to what could be going on? Thanks

Comment: Not directly relevant, but are you sure you are calling `Model.find` and not `Model.findOne` ? `Model.find` returns an array so `match.set` would be undefined an throw an error

Comment: Ah, I am actually using `findOne` and not `find`. I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.set()` is not meant to save the document to the database. You can use `document.set()` to modify the local document, when you want to save the modification to the database use `document.save()`

```
match.set({ fizz: obj.fizz });
await match.save();
```

**Tip:**
You can use the following to upsert a document if your `obj` only contains `foo`, `bar`, `fizz` and you want to update `fizz`

```
await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { foo: obj.foo, bar: obj.bar }, 
  { $set: { fizz: obj.fizz } },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

After execute set statement than execute save statement